# move_uploaded_file is working in the localhost but not in the server

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using move_uploaded_file to transfer some files that I selected to the other folder. It's working on my localhost but not in our server. I don't know why. Here are my codes.

```
   <?php
     include('connect.php');
     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
       $position = $_POST['position'];
       $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
       $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
       $contact_number = $_POST['contact_number'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $status = 'NO';

       $resume = $_FILES['resume']['name'];
       $resume_tmp = $_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'];
       $ret=explode('.',$_FILES['resume']['name']);
       $file_ext=array_pop($ret);
       $extensions = array("pdf","docx");

       if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions )=== false){
        echo "<script> alert('Unsupported format')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.location='index.php';</script>";
       }
       else{    
            move_uploaded_file($resume_tmp,"resume/$resume");
            $query=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO                   applicants(position,first_name,last_name,contact_number,email,resume,status) VALUES (:position,:first_name,:last_name,:contact_number,:email,:resume,:status)");
            $query->bindParam(':position',$position);
            $query->bindParam(':first_name',$first_name);
            $query->bindParam(':last_name',$last_name);
            $query->bindParam(':contact_number',$contact_number);
            $query->bindParam(':email',$email);
            $query->bindParam(':resume',$resume);
            $query->bindParam(':status',$status);
            $query->execute();

            echo "<script> alert('You Successfully Applied to this Job')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.location='index.php';</script>";
      }   
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: please use ini_set("display_errors","1");
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1); at starting will show what error you getting.

Comment: Does the resume directory exist on the server?

Comment: the resume directory is existing in our server, but the files are not uploaded to that directory

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(resume/file.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in/var/www/site.com/public_html/view.php

here is the warning

Comment: The code is in fact moving the uploaded file to the resume directory. Permission is denied either because the directory doesn't exist or it does not have the correct permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if upload directory exist or not. and then change its permission 777 all writable.

```
$file = "images";
if(is_dir($file))
{
echo ("$file is a directory");
}
else
{
echo ("$file is not a directory");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by changing the folder permissions to 777.
Go to your file manager and select change permissions.
Make it all writable.
That's all.